# How is graph theory used to solve problems in number theory?

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory, applications

What are some applications of graph theory in number theory? How can a graph theory approach be useful to solving number theory problems? In general, is graph theory ever useful in making number theory problems simpler or easier to understand? When is this the case?

Comment: http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/Publications2/An%20application%20of%20graph%20theory%20to%20additive%20number%20theory.pdf

Comment: Do you know of any more general applications or applications in other problems?

Comment: http://www.math.bme.hu/~balint/oktatas/perkolacio/percolation_papers/temperley_lieb.pdf

Comment: In general terms, what kind of approach by means of grapht ehory is used to solve number theory problems?

Comment: What I would like to know is:  In general, is graph theory ever useful in making number theory problems simpler or easier to understand? When is this the case?

Comment: http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1969-14.pdf also http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5975/approaching-number-theory-conjectures-through-graph-theory

Comment: One way that graph theory can be used to understand the relationship of coprimes in is "prime graphs." A graph is called "prime" if you can label the vertices with labels $p_i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$ such that adjacent vertices have coprime labels. The conjecture that all trees are prime is still open.